# Date Time Parsing Dart

Tags: android, datetime, flutter, dart

what i m trying to convert string "09-Apr-20" into "yyyy-MM-dd" format.

I have tried

```
DateTime tempDate = new DateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").parse("09-Apr-20");
print(tempDate);
```

But it gave me error

```
FormatException: Trying to read MM from 09-Apr-20 at position 3
```

after some searching i found out "dd-MMM-yy" cannot parsed by DateFormat method in dart.

So, how to parse this type of String.

Looking for answer, kindly help me out :)

Comment: Your question is rather confusing.  `MMM` should work fine to parse `Apr`, and the error message you cite is because you used `MM` instead.  [`yy` currently does not work as documented](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/123), and for now, you can check that the returned year is in the range [0, 100) and make your own adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

This only works if all dates are after year 2000. I only recommend the use of this code as a hotfix.

**Hotfix:**

```
    String hotfixYear (String _) => _.substring(0,_.length-2)+"20"+(_.substring(_.length-2, _.length));
```

**Use:**

```
DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(hotfixYear("09-Apr-20"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of a hack but I ended up with some very interesting/annoying bugs about two-digits years:

- https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/275
- https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/123

So my hack is to define the `dateTimeConstructor` so it adds 2000 to the year.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  final dateFormat = DateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");

  // Workaround for issue 123 and 275 in the intl package for parsing years with two digit.
  // The logic could be more advanced but will for know just add 2000 to the year.
  dateFormat.dateTimeConstructor = (int year, int month, int day,
      int hour24, int minute, int second, int fractionalSecond, bool utc) {
    if (utc) {
      return DateTime.utc(
          year + 2000, month, day, hour24, minute, second, fractionalSecond);
    } else {
      return DateTime(
          year + 2000, month, day, hour24, minute, second, fractionalSecond);
    }
  };

  print(dateFormat.parse('09-Apr-20')); // 2020-04-09 00:00:00.000
}
```

Please notices that the hack is a workaround for a current bug in the package which are properly being fixed in the future. I will therefore recommend to subscribe to the two issues and make sure to test the solution after an update of the Flutter SDK and/or the intl package.

Comment: Please don't unconditionally add 2000.  Your code will break when `yy` is fixed in `package:intl`.  Instead check that the year is in the range [0, 99] first.  I actually have a pending fix for `yy`, but incorrect hacks to fix the year mean that it will be a breaking change, complicating and delaying its release.

Comment: Well, it is a workaround for the current problem of the package (and is a lot better workaround that the one suggested in issue 123). I guess that if people are going to use this workaround, then they should subscribe on the two issues so they are notified when the issues are fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MMM` and make the year 4 digits.

```
DateTime tempDate = DateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").parse("09-Apr-2020");
```

If you want the first 2 digits to be the first 2 digits of the current Millennium then use this

```
 DateTime time = DateFormat("dd-MMM-yy").parse("09-Apr-20");
 String now = DateTime.now().year.toString();
 String timeString = time.toString().replaceRange(0, 1, now.substring(0, 1));
 timeString.replaceRange(1, 2, now.substring(1, 2));
 print(timeString);
```

Comment: I can inform you that using yy in this case will parse the year as: 0020. :)

Comment: Interesting. Maybe there are a difference between the `DateFormat` in Flutter and the class from the `intl` package.

Comment: [`yy` is known to not work as documented](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/issues/123).

Comment: I have just tested you line with `intl` and it gives: `0020-04-09 00:00:00.000`. But again, there could be a difference in the Flutter SDK which I am not using. I just expected that Flutter used the intl package since the package is part of the path of the URL in the API documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

Comment: Ok, you changed you input to `09-Apr-2020` which are indeed working but are not the input from the question. :)